# How to import fields from a mysql db to a dynamically populated menu in html?

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql

I am working on a project that will do unit conversion, similar to google's conversion tool where you can select "Mass" for example and convert grams to pounds.

I chose to use a mySQL database to store the units I'm going to convert to/from as well as the type of unit (mass, temperature, etc) in a table. I want to have the page display the types initially, then use jquery's .change() to load in the fields for the "to" and "from" menus based on the initial type selection, which will be returned from a query to the mysql db.

For context, I know this is a needlessly complicated approach, I'm using this project to better familiarize myself with jquery and php.

At the moment the web page displays the options for the first menu but .change() does not appear to be calling the php file, so the other menus remain empty. The php file will load the db results if you replace $choice with one of the unit types listed in the html options, so I know I can successfully query the database.

My question is how to import that data to the menu on the webpage?

Here is my html file:

```
<script src = "http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(function(){$("#first-choice").change(function() {$("#second-choice").load
    ("getter.php?choice=" + $("#first-choice").val()); } );
}   
</script>
</head>

<body>
    <h1>Conversion Tool</h1>
    <div id="conversionSelect">
        <p>

        Amount: <input type = text> 
        Convert From: <select id = "first-choice">
          <option value="Heat">Heat</option>
          <option value="Length">Length</option>
          <option value="Mass">Mass</option>
          <option value="Time">Time</option>
          <option value = "Volume">Volume</option>

        </select>

        Convert From: <select id ="second-choice">
            <option> Select unit type </option>
        </select>

        Convert To: <select id = "third-choice">
             <option> Select unit type </option>
        </select>

        </p>

</div><!-- end of input form div -->
```

And this is the php file:

```
<?php
    $username = "root";
    $password = "";
    $hostname = "localhost";
    $db = "converter";
    $port=3306;
    $socket="";

    $dbhandle = new mysqli($hostname, $username, $password, $db);
    $choice = $_GET['choice'];

    $query = "SELECT Unit FROM unittable WHERE UnitType = '$choice'";

    $result = $dbhandle->query($query);

    if ($row = $dbhandle->prepare($query)) {
            $row->execute();
            $row->bind_result($Unit);

            while ($row->fetch()) {
                echo "<option>" .$Unit. "</option>";
            }
        $row->close();
    }
    $dbhandle->close();
?>
```

Comment: You really don't need a database for that, just store the conversion information in a javascript object and call it a day.

Comment: `$("#first-choice")` and `$("#firstchoice")` Is one of those a TYPO

Comment: Yes, I made some edits to correct that in the post. Thank you for pointing that out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

C:\xampp\htdocs\getter.php
This is not how you run ajax request for php file.
If your getter.php file is in same path from where you are making ajax request write it like: getter.php

```
<script src = "http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"> 
$(function(){
    $("#first-choice").change(function() {
        $("#second-choice")
        .load("getter.php?choice=" + $("#firstchoice").val()); 
    });
}   
</script>
```

Comment: `#second-      choice` may cause a problem also